# How do you set nav on left side and add animation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a beginner learning html css So I'm facing issues with how to change navigation bar from right to left and add animation

I tried but it's seem to be stopped there on right side
I want to make navigation bar responsive and look and feel good

Comment: Where is your code ?